# How to end the process executed during COM automation

Tags: c++, com, ole

Here is the code that runs Ms Word in the background for OLE automation:

```c++
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    CLSID clsid;
    HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Word.Application", &clsid);

    IDispatch *pWApp;
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
         //here the process starts
         hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
                               IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pWApp);

         cout << "success" << endl;
    }

    //here I try to end it
    pWApp->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, Word remains in memory after my program has ended. How to stop it?

Comment: I believe it's normal for the server to remain in memory for a few minutes before exiting if no clients are using it

Comment: @M.M Ahh, so nothing else must be done?

Comment: I don't know about MS Word specifically; your code looks correct though, the server behaviour is up to the server itself

Comment: Try [`Quit` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/application-quit-method-word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Word.Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/application-object-word) object that you are creating has a [`Quit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/application-quit-method-word) method that you can optionally call before you `Release()` your interface pointer to the object:

> Quits Microsoft Word and optionally saves or routes the open documents.

Since you have an [`IDispatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608.aspx) interface to the object, you can use the [`IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221306.aspx) and [`IDispatch::Invoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479.aspx) methods in order to call the `Word.Application.Quit()` method, eg:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        CLSID clsid;
        hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Word.Application", &clsid);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            IDispatch *pWApp;
            hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pWApp);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                cout << "success" << endl;

                // use pWApp as needed ...

                DISPID dispID;
                LPOLESTR ptName = L"Quit"; //name of the method
                hr = pWApp->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &ptName, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &dispID);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    //no parameters
                    DISPPARAMS dp = {NULL, NULL, 0, 0};
                    hr = pWApp->Invoke(dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &dp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                }

                pWApp->Release();
            }
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added the working code to your answer to make it better.